# How to route a url to another url on a router

Tags: router, wireless-router, routing, url

So, here is the scenario.

I have an iPad app what communicates with my production server. The app syncs data to the server. The sync is stuck for some reason. Their is a way for me to test it on the server, but would cause much work and possible down time. Not good. I can test a beta app that connects to a development computer, but the beta app is not having the problems. Data loss is not really acceptable, screen shots of all the data and then manually input the data is ridiculous for several iPad's.

My only thought was to use a wireless router to reroute the iPad app to the development computer to find out what the issue is and/or use other software to obtain the data.

Like URL rewriting hardware. I don't even need to route the URL, I have the IP addresses.

Comment: you could try arp poisoning the router. this would provide the effect you are looking for. if the ipad is jailbroken, then you would only need to edit its host file

Comment: Not jailbroken, these are not my iPad's. There is around 6 currently that are having this issue. There must be a way to re-route an IP address on a router!!??

Answer (score 1):

Your router may or may not have that feature. If it does not, then the answer would be to put a more robust routing software on it and place it in front of the wireless router.

You would then be able to redirect any traffic you wanted.

ARP poisoning would be an easier solution in my opinion, unless of course your router has that feature.

There are many tutorials on google that explain the process of ARP poisoing

If that is not how you would like to go about it, I would look into Smoothwall. It is very powerful and fairly simple to setup. It also has a squid proxy built in that I imagine could do that job. If not then it has a hosts file.